# In ag-grid, toggle between tree view and flat view is not working

Tags: treeview, ag-grid-react

I need to present data as a flat view or tree view depending on the data I get. It works fine in the latest `ag-grid-enterprise` version `30.2.0`. Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-toggle-tree-data-dzvlhx You can toggle between flat view and tree view by clicking the button at the top.

[image]
[image]

However, it doesn't work in `@ag-grid-enterprise` version `27.2.1`. It won't show the tree view column when I try to switch to tree view by clicking the button at the top. Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-toggle-tree-data-issue-w676w4

[image]

I wonder if it is `ag-grid` version issue or I'm missing anything. I appreciate your help. Thank you.